# What is an example of violating class affinity?

Tags: wpf, affinity, uielementcollection

The page on [UICollectionClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection?view=netframework-4.8) (from the Microsoft WPF libraries) has the following note:

> A UIElementCollection has affinity to its own context (class). You
>   must access the collection from the context of the owning Panel.

What is an example of an incorrect way of using this class where I would run into the problem cited above?

[image]

Comment: @Clemens So the affinity being referenced is about threading.  But could my question be reopened, as I am asking for an example of incorrect usage?

Comment: Incorrect usage would obviously be trying to access a DispatcherObject from a thread other than the one in which it was created.